# Can people no longer ask questions about what Trinitarians think?

Tags: discussion

So a mod closed [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/91059/according-to-trinitarians-does-god-the-father-have-a-god).

Am I to take this to mean questions about Trinitarianism, Binitarianism, or Unitarianism are now considered off-topic?

Comment: I am also rather confused about why it was closed.

Comment: I think the question is definitely fine after the edits, thanks.

Comment: Wow - no dissention allowed - apparently! Answer summarily deleted. I thought it was polite, factual and on topic.

Comment: @steveowen Dissention is always allowed. Insulting people, like you did in your second paragraph, is not.

Comment: There is a big difference to being insulting and being insulted. If the facts cause insult then so be it - it's the fact's fault then. So if the offending para is edited will you reopen?

Comment: @steveowen It's not a fact that it's pointless asking questions to Trinitarians, that's your opinion. And even if you think it's true, you should be able to refrain from saying it. You can speak respectfully of people you disagree with instead of calling their beliefs "unbiblical, made-up". Almost everyone else on this site is able to acknowledge that there are alternative interpretations of the scriptures, even if they think the interpretations are very weak. If you can't see that people you disagree with connect their beliefs to the scriptures then you're going to have trouble on this site.

Comment: Yes, if you edit your post enough then of course we'll undelete it.

Answer (score 2):

You're asking about the Nature of God and the meaning of the word "Has", not Trinitarian Theology. It doesn't matter if someone's a Trinitarian a Bilaterian or you accept Mary into the Godhead.

The word "Has" means one thing, "My".

Also, your title doesn't match the content of the question.  I think you just mean to ask about the relationship between the Second and Third Persons of the Trinity, but it could be because your religious scruples prevent you from uttering words like "Persons of the Trinity" you're unable to phrase the question in such a way - and I respect that.  But it's CONFUSING and I have no idea what you're asking and if you think that DJclayworths answer supported your assertion that "Jesus Has as God" you're way off base.

When somebody IS God, they don't HAVE a God, they ARE God.  If Poseidon is a god, Poseidon's god is not Zeus - Poseidon's master is God.  To suggest otherwise is to say there's a hierarchy that it would take you 18 seconds to realize that no Trinitarian who hasn't been dead for 800 years thinks exists. Which is another reason to close a question.

But I closed the question because it is meant as a paradoxical trap question, which is a problem for philosophy majors, not Christian theology.  The Trinity is a mystery, you can ask questions all day long, but if the only answer is "it's a mystery" there's no point in asking questions about what Trinitarians think.

On top of that, I think I gave you a pretty simple piece of advice to rephrase the question.  But you wrote up this meta post before I could even finish typing my close reason comment.

Comment: Jesus explicitly says "My God, my God". WTH are you talking about here?! You don't seem to think the issue is worth grappling with, but that's *your opinion*.

Comment: Up-voted because your answer clearly shows how theological bias is affecting the mods.

Comment: "take you 18 seconds to realize that no Trinitarian who hasn't been dead for 800 years thinks exists" DJ's answer, which currently has 9 up votes, says "Only he [i.e., Jesus] "has" a God **in the sense we normally use it**."

Comment: The question isn't intended as a 'paradoxical trap', and if the only answer is 'it's a mystery' that's an important and valuable piece of information. Not reason to close the question. I am trying to understand Trinitarianism better - I'm sorry if my simple, obvious (to me) questions are leading to paradoxes and mysteries for your position.

Comment: Or look at andrewtc's answer. "we have no problem saying that the Father is “God” to Jesus, by virtue of Christ’s willing subjection to Him" He even clarified in the comments that Jesus still has a God (after his ascension).

Comment: GratefulDisciple clarifies the sense in which Jesus has a God. "Instead, it's better to say that Jesus in his human nature (as Second Adam, as a son of God as we all are) HAS A RELATIONSHIP to God the Father (the divine being)." So the top 3 answers as of right now all affirm Jesus has a God, although qualifying it in various ways.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather It's still a little irritating that you didn't fix the title of that question.  You mind if I do it?  You're not really asking if God the Father has a God who is higher than Him are you?  Aren't you only asking about God the Son and maybe the Holy Spirit?

Comment: What do you want to change it to? I'm not specifying whether the Father's God would be higher than him, just whether He has a God.

Comment: Just whether "God the Son has a God?"  Mainly because asking whether God the Father has a God is not something anyone would ever think of and isn't something you're remotely asking for a scriptural refutation or proof of.

Comment: Well, that's a different question ... I think both the question as it stands and your question would lead to similar discussion, tho'. So answering whether the Father has a God leads to what it means for the Son to (apparently) have a God.